# Problem with C language, I don't understand the error

Tags: c

I'm learning C but I don't understand why the error appears on line number 9
--->    scanf("%[^\n]s",&cadena);      // i tried with "%s" but still doesnt work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char cadena[40];

    printf("Ingrese cadena: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&cadena);
    printf("La cadena es %s \n", cadena);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: "*why the error*" What error? Please post the exact error you are getting. Hint: #1: `"%[^\n]s"` you don't need the `s` there. Hint #2: `&cadena` you want `&cadena[0]` or just `cadena`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior on all but non-conforming compilers. It does not do what you think it is doing (except on MS compilers) There is no `'s'` after `"%[...]"` the `"%[...]"` conversion specifier is a complete specifier on its own.

Comment: `cadena` is already a pointer [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "`cadena` is already a pointer" -->It is an array.

Comment: `candena` is converted to a pointer on access.... (I get your drift though, I was referring to its use in `scanf()` and the lack of need for `&`)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Indeed, the _object_ `cadena` is an array, but the expression `cadena` is just a pointer (a pointer to `char`), and, indeed, `&cadena` is also a pointer (in this case a pointer to an array of a fixed number of chars)  So you are right... or not.  It depends on the context.  In the case you are commenting, it is a pointer value, as we are talking about an expression.  Don't be pedantic in excess, because you can err.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the ampersand on cadena in scanf

```
scanf("%[^\n]", cadena);
```

An array decays to a pointer so you were actually passing a pointer to a pointer in that case.

Also you can just write it like this

```
scanf("%s",cadena);
```

Depends on your end goal though.